# Is there a way to convert a ping (icmp) packet to a TCP packet?

Tags: networking, tcp, proxy, ping, agent

I want the PING package to go through the proxy program, but the program only supports forwarding packets from the TCP layer and does not support forwarding ICMP packets.

Is there any solution?

Comment: You could better specify your problem. In fact, if you are looking for a tool the referred "serverfault" platform is suitable since stackoverflow is about programming issues.

Comment: Thanks for that advice.

Comment: But I'm looking for a way to convert icmp packet to tcp packet, it means I have to use "ping" program.

Comment: It seems not feaseble. You would have to implement a bridge in the middle, intercepting ICMP Pings and converting to "TCP ping". Anyway, the icmp ping back would not be a ping anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a tool, you can use a software like [psping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psping), [paping](https://code.google.com/archive/p/paping/) and [tcping](https://elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php). They test time response similar as ICMP Ping but over TCP.

If you need to implement by hand, you may use SYN package and its response (SYN ACK) to measure. For C#, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067342/how-to-implement-psping-tcp-ping-in-c-sharp) thread is discussing the implementation.